# Finding four digit number ABCD such that $ABCD \div DCBA = 9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle, decimal-expansion

If $(ABCD) \div (DCBA)=9$ where $A,B,C$ and $D$ are distinct and all them belong to ${0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}$ but $A$ and $D $are not equal to zero then find $A,B ,C$ and $D$. I tried with the decimal expansion and I couldn't arrive at the solution

Comment: So DCBA is a 4-digit number whose product with $9$ is a 4-digit number. That should restrict things a lot.

Comment: @Akshay, do you reckon we could have let Achari figure that out on his own? Why take away his joy of discovery?

Comment: ABCD is divisible by 9, therefore DCBA also. Therefore ABCD is divisible by 81. A+B+C+D=9k. Therefore, 111A + 11B + C + k is also divisible by 9.

Comment: Since 9 | DCBA, 81 | 9 x DCBA = ABCD.

Comment: I would just like to observe that $1089\cdot k$ is the reverse of $1089\cdot (10-k)$ for every $1\le k \le 9$.

Answer (score 6):

D has to be 1 and A has to be 9,
so the problem becomes
9BC1=9x1CB9.

Either C=0 or C > 1.
If C>1, 9xC would overflow
to the next digit,
which it can't.
Therefore,
C=0 and the problem becomes
9B01=9x10B9.

In values,
9001+100B = 9x1009+90B
or
10B = 9081-9001=80
or B=8.

The final solution is
9801 = 9 x 1089.

Comment: Please present the logical steps

Comment: I think you would learn more if you figured out the steps yourself, Achari. In my opinion, marty has done too much for you already.

Comment: I entered the steps as I solved it. I did not know the answer in advance and interpreted this as a challenge. Also, this pushed me to 20,000, which feels good.

Comment: Congratulations on 20,000.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem in this way just for fun. Marty Cohen's method is better.

Note that the problem statement is equivalent to $ABCD=9\cdot DCBA=(10-1)DCBA=DCBA\cdot 10-DCBA=DCBA0-DCBA$

This tells us that

$$\begin{array}{cccccc}
  & D & C & B & A & 0 \\
- & 0 & D & C & B & A\\\hline 
  & 0 & A & B & C & D\end{array}
$$

Now note that since $D$ cannot be $0$, it must be $1$ (why?)

If you understand the hint, you should be able to continue this train of reasoning. If not,don't hesitate to ask for another hint.

Comment: Nice and simple solution... +1 for this....

Comment: @MJD, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

At about midnight last night,
I realized that my answer
works for *any* base,
not just decimal,
so I am making this explicit here.

Let b be the base,
where b >= 4.
Digits in base b
that are expressions
are surrounded by parenthesis.
The two used here are
(b-1) and (b-2),
which are the largest two digits in base b.

Here is the problem:

If ABCD and DCBA are
4-digit numbers in base B
with all digits distinct
and A and D non-zero,
and ABCD = (b-1) x DCBA
 ("x" indicates multiplication),
determine the numbers.

Solution:

If D > 1,
the product would have five digits.
Therefore
D=1 and A=(b-1).

If C>1, the product
(b-1)xC would overflow
and, again,
the product would be five digits.
Since 1 is already taken,
C=0.

The problem is now
(b-1) B 0 1 = (b-1) x 1 0 B (b-1).
Getting rid of the high-order digit,
this becomes
 B 0 1 = (b-1) x  B (b-1).
Converting to values,
Bb^2+1 = (b-1)(Bb+b-1)
=Bb^2-Bb+b^2-2b+1
or
Bb = b^2-2b
=b(b-2)
or
B = (b-2).

The solution is therefore

(b-1)(b-2) 0 1 = (b-1) x 1 0 (b-2) (b-1).